# Related Entries not sorting correctly

Tags: entries-field, sorting

Craft 3.0.16.1

I have a relationship that is outputting entries, but the entries are not in the order as selected.

```
{# not sorting correctly  - **fieldName** is a variable passed via include #}
{% set relatedEntries = publications.relatedTo(
  {sourceElement: country, field: fieldName}
) %}
```

I copied this [code from the documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/entries-fields.html) and change field names to work

```
{# copied from docs but template errors #}
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries({
    relatedTo: { sourceElement: country, field: fieldName },
    orderBy:     "sortOrder",
    limit:     null
}) %}
```

but this throws a database exception error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sortOrder' in
>   'order clause'

How do I get related entries to sort on the order as selected in the entries field?

********************UPDATE**********************

HERE IS THE FULL TEMPLATE

```
  <li class="accordion-item {#{% if loop.first %}is-active{% endif %}#}" data-accordion-item>
    <!-- Accordion tab title -->
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">
      {{ categoryTitle  }}
      <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i><!-- /.arrow right -->
    </a>

    <!-- Accordion tab content: it would start in the open state due to using the `is-active` state class. -->
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>

      {# start tabbed content #}
      <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="cat-{{ hash }} ">

       {# inside categories list countries #}
      {% for country in countries.all() %}  
        <li class="tabs-title {#{% if loop.first %}is-active{% endif %}#}"><a href="#{{ country.slug }}" aria-selected="true" data-tabs-target="{{ country.slug }}">{{ country.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %} {# end countries loop #}
      </ul>


      <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="cat-{{ hash }}">
        {% for country in countries.all() %}
        <div class="tabs-panel {#{% if loop.first %}is-active{% endif %}#}" id="{{ country.slug }}">
          <ul class="no-bullet pubs full-width">

            {# finally output entries that are in the category and country #}

            {# not sorting correctly #}
            {% set relatedEntries = publications.relatedTo(                   {sourceElement: country, field: fieldName}
            ) %}

            {# error about method ('all') on an array #}
            {# {% set relatedEntries = country[fieldName].all() %} #}

            {# 
            // copied from docs but template errors
            {% set relatedEntries = craft.entries({
                relatedTo: { sourceElement: country, field: fieldName },
                orderBy:     "sortOrder",
                limit:     null
            }) %} #}



            {% for entry in relatedEntries.all() %}

              {% for block in entry.Documents.all() %}
                {% if block.externalLink|length %}
                  {# use external link field #}
                  {% set link = block.externalLink %}
                {% else %}
                  {# use uploaded file #}
                  {% set link = block.pdfOrFile.one().url ?? null%}
                {% endif %}

                <li><a href="{{ link }}" target="_blank">
                  <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
                  <div class="icon-holder">
                    <img src="/assets/img/next.svg" alt="" class="go-icon">
                  </div><!-- /.icon-holder --></a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}{#end link #}

              {% else %}
              {# output nothing for no results #}
            {% endfor %}

          </ul><!-- /.no-bullet pubs -->
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      {# end tabbed content #}      

    </div><!--accordion content-->
  </li>
```

Comment: You trying to output a list of entries that were selected in an Entries field (in the order selected), is that right?

Comment: @SimonKuran Yes that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include templates and pass multiple different variables to them with different types that may have a different field layout it is required to [code defensively](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#defensive-coding-in-twig) and check for variable types. Actually you should **never** print something without further checking. Anything bad that could happen will happen. Especially in such a case

```
{% if country[fieldhandle] is defined and country[fieldhandle] is not empty and  %}
    {% for element in country.getFieldValue(fieldhandle).all() %}
        {{ element.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

You may as well include a [instance of](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tests.html#instance-of) check

```
{% if element.getFieldValue(fieldHandle) is instance of('craft\\elements\\db\\ElementQuery') %}
    {% set relatedElements = element.getFieldValue(fieldHandle).all() %}
{% else %}
    // eager loading, the result is an array, no need to fetch it
    {% set relatedElements = element.getFieldValue(fieldHandle) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Robin - I"m not sure what you mean.  but I tried your code and got an error `impossible to invoke a method ("all") on an array. I really need to be able to have these entries output in a specific order.

Comment: Do you eager load them? Because that would be a reason why it is not working, normally that field is a default query.. You can sort the results as you like

Comment: Not eager loading - have updated the original post with the full template code.

Comment: Where do you set the `fieldName` variable? I'm a little bit confused, because you just have to call `entry.field.all()`

Comment: That's coming through an include ```    {% include '_includes/pub-section' with {
      "categoryTitle" : "Market Monitor",
      "hash"          : "market-monitor",
      "fieldName"     : "marketMonitor"
    } %}```

Comment: And your `countries` query? As already said Craft provides the order by default unless you changed it in the query

Comment: countries is set in the parent template {% set countries = craft.entries.section('countries') %} and then a for loop goes over it in the include